# No Window Icon Using SDL_SetWindowIcon()

Tags: c++, linux, sdl-2

I'm currently developing a game with SDL2 in C++ and I want to set my game's icon for the task bar and for the Alt-Tab switcher. I am trying to achieve this by using SDL_SetWindowIcon():

```
SDL_Surface* icon = IMG_Load("icon.png");
SDL_SetWindowIcon(sdlWindow, icon);
```

Even if my window is correctly initialized and the surface is loaded, the icon does not appear in the task bar or in the Alt-Tab switcher. I am on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not going to claim that I understand how this function works, but I can share with you how I got it to work. Even though I could use a 600x600 (pixels) image in the desktop.my_app file, and using that launcher would work fine, SDL2 would NOT load a 600x600 image. I tried 128x128 too, and that didn't work.

Changing the image size to 64x64 miraculously fixed it. Storage issue? I don't know why SDL2 can handle huge SDL_Surface s in other parts of the app but not the window icon....

Answer (score -1):

Rather then taking this tough path, if you set Icon through the IDE it will appear everywhere, I mean everywhere such as File explorer, Taskbar, SDL Window or its(exe) shortcut etc.

follow these steps for Visual Studio
You need to use an .ico file. You cannot use a PNG image file for your executable's icon, it will not work. You must use .ico. There are online converters available for image to .ico files.
I will recommend this https://convertico.com/
because it was multiple icons in single file option which many tools dont provide (this is not a promotion/Ad)
The ico used for your exe will be the ico with the LOWEST RESOURCE ID. In order to change the .ico

1. Open VIEW > RESOURCE VIEW (in the middle of the VIEW menu), or press Ctrl+Shift+E to get it to appear.
2. In Resource view, right click the project name and right click "**ADD**" -> "**RESOURCE...**"
   [image]
3. Single Click on "Icon" then from the list of many items, then click "IMPORT..".
   [image]
4. When a file selection will open *.ico files aren't listed, and you can't use a regular PNG or JPG image as an icon, so change the file filter to *.ico using the dropdown.
   [image]
5. Now you are done. you can see the icon available everywhere
   [image]
6. If you load a bunch of ICO files into the project for whatever reason, be sure the .ico you want Visual Studio to use has the lowest id in resource.h. You can edit this file manually with no problems

Eg.

```
//resource.h
#define IDI_ICON1                       102
#define IDI_ICON2                       103
```

IDI_ICON1 is used

```
//resource.h
#define IDI_ICON1                       106
#define IDI_ICON2                       103
```

Now IDI_ICON2 is used.